# How to convert node.js Buffer to JavaScript object without an intermediate string

Tags: json, node.js, buffer

I have a `Buffer` instance which contains utf-8 JSON.

Usually you convert it this way:

```
const buffer = Buffer.from('{"a":1}')
const str = buffer.toString("utf-8")
const obj = JSON.parse(str)
```

To make the Buffer->Object conversion more performant how would I convert it without an intermediate string?

Comment: Interested. https://hackernoon.com/https-medium-com-amanhimself-converting-a-buffer-to-json-and-utf8-strings-in-nodejs-2150b1e3de57.

Comment: @AjAX. The code by your link creates an intermediate string. I'm looking for a way to avoid any intermediate strings (or any other intermediate data).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `JSON.parse` can accept `Buffer` instances.

```
const buffer = Buffer.from('{"a":1}')
const obj = JSON.parse(buffer)
```

Comment: That’s what said in the link.

Comment: @AjAX. Nope. The link does not say so.

Comment: [”Convert a Buffer to JSON. Buffers can convert to JSON.”](https://hackernoon.com/https-medium-com-amanhimself-converting-a-buffer-to-json-and-utf8-strings-in-nodejs-2150b1e3de57) Even the `URL` says it.

Comment: Yes. Also all the code examples create intermediate string variables. And my question states that this is exactly what I want to avoid.

Comment: JSON.parse does not accept Buffer: `Type 'Buffer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'`

Comment: This: `console.log(JSON.parse(Buffer.from('{"a":1}')))` prints this: `{ a: 1 }` in node.js v4 or later. Looks like you are using TypeScript, not JavaScript.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still converts the buffer to string under the hood: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66994351/1202251