# Does JSON.parse() accepts a Buffer as argument?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

The following code works in Node.js `v14.16.0`. However, I can't find any documentation indicating that `JSON.parse()` accepts a `Buffer` as the argument. Is this expected behavior—yet not documented—or perhaps I'm doing something wrong?

```
const fs = require('fs');
const dataPayload = fs.readFileSync('data.json'); // a buffer
const data = JSON.parse(dataPayload);

console.log(data); // { name: 'Jane', age: 24 } -> an object
```

Contents of `data.json`:

```
{
  "name": "Jane",
  "age": 24
}
```

The [spec](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-15.12.2) does not mention anything related to this.

Comment: Afaik, if the passed object isn't a string, JSON.parse() calls `.toString()` on it first. A common beginner's error for instance is passing objects to JSON.parse(), this will lead to JSON.parse complaining about an unexpected character `o` because it tries to parse `"[object Object]"`

Comment: Same as [`dataPayload.toString()`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end)

Answer (score 6):

It ends up converting the Buffer to a string and that is described in the ECMAScript spec when you pass an Object to `JSON.parse(text [,reviver])`.

The [ECMAScript spec](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-15.12.2) for `JSON.parse()` contains this first step:

```
Let JText be ToString(text).
```

So, the very first step is to take the first argument you pass to `JSON.parse(text)` and convert it to a string if it's not already.  If you want to see how `ToString(text)` works, that is described [here in the spec](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-9.8).  In this case, a Buffer would be an Object so it would follow that path which calls the internal `ToPrimitive()` with a hint of string as the type and then calling the internal `ToString()` on that.

---

Here's a little example that runs in a snippet to show that it's using the `.toString()` method on the object:

```js
let data = {
    toString() {
         console.log(`".toString()" method called`);
         return "[1,2,3]";    // return some JSON
    }
};

let test = JSON.parse(data);

console.log(`Is this an array: ${Array.isArray(test)}`);
console.log(`Array of length: ${test.length}`);
console.log(test);
```